# Moving named ranges with moving columns

Tags: excel, range, move, named, col

I am using [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) 2010 and Windows 7.

Suppose I have a sheet with data in columns A to F. Also the text in the third row cell is used as captiontext for a label on a userform. But since both cell value and column number can change I cannot look for a fixed cell or value.

For each column I have a named range defined, which are all different in size. For column A this is "MyRange". I can have the label look for the text in the third row cell within that range.

What I need is, that when I cut and paste/insert e.g old column A as new column D, "MyRange" automatically points to the new location of that column. I want to use VBA to accomplish this.

In [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e45ee5bd-ec38-4976-8754-a47e71e6a425/after-sorting-namedrange-positions-are-broken) I read about a relative Refersto formula, but that doesn't do what I need.

Thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this specific problem is not to look at named ranges but use the named cell function. 
Still I would like to know if it is possible to do this with named ranges.

Rob